# In Scala, how to test the type of an 'Any' object against a type with type parameter?

Tags: scala, pattern-matching, type-erasure

I am trying to get a type-safe way of converting the result of parsing a JSON string. I want to check whether a field is Map[String, any] or a plain string. My first attempt is

```
def test(x:Any) = {
    x match {
        case m:Map[String,Any] => ...
        ...
}
```

This causes "non-variable type argument String in type pattern Map[String,Any] is unchecked since it is eliminated by erasure"

Looking through the document of TypeTag and ClassTag, I could not find a good way to accomplish that. The following code does not cause the warning, but I wonder why it works.

```
type StringMap = Map[String,Any]
def test(x:Any) = {
    x match {
        case m:StringMap => ...
        ...
}
```

Comment: Just because the compiler is not complaining does't mean the second solution works.  Using either piece of code, a Map defined as `Map(1 -> 2)` would hit on that match condition even though that's not what you want.

Comment: Outside of some very low-level code, method signatures using `Any` or `Map[String, Any]` should be virtually non-existent in well designed Scala code.

Answer (score 5):

It was a bug.  It's fixed in 2.11:

```
scala> type StringMap = Map[String, Any]
defined type alias StringMap

scala> (Map(4 -> true): Any) match {
     |   case m: StringMap => true
     |   case _ => false
     | }
<console>:10: warning: non-variable type argument String in type pattern scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Any] (the underlying of StringMap) is unchecked since it is eliminated by erasure
                case m: StringMap => true
                        ^
res0: Boolean = true
```

The reason it doesn't work is that you can't tell, due to erasure, what the type arguments were.  If you want to be sure it's a `Map[String, Any]` instead of some other kind of map, you have to go check every key and make sure it's a `String`.

```
case m: Map[_,_] if m.keySet.forall(_.isInstanceOf[String]) => 
  m.asInstanceOf[Map[String,Any]]
```

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible to check the type parameters, but

> I want to check whether a field is Map[String, any] or a plain string

is easy:

```
x match {
  case s: String => ...
  // you can add cases for numbers, etc. here
  case m: Map[_, _] => ... m.asInstanceOf[Map[String, Any]]
}
```

> Looking through the document of TypeTag and ClassTag, I could not find a good way to accomplish that.

Tags are created by the compiler using static type information, so in your case you'll only have class or type tag of `Any`.