# How to match typed nested map?

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

I have `Map[String, Any]`, for example from JSON deserializer:

```
def map: Map[String, Any] = Map("hello" -> Map("world" -> "value"))
```

And I want to get `Option` of nested key `"hello"."world"`:

```
val value = map.get("hello").flatMap {
  case m: Map[String, String] => m.get("value")
  case _ => None
}

assert(value == Some("value"))
```

But this solution is not type safe - it emits warning 'is unchecked since it is eliminated by erasure' and will fail on wrong value type.

How to accomplish this the safe way? Returning value if nested object is a map of valid/compatible type containing key `"world"` or `None` otherwise?

edit: This is not about `Manifest[]` or `TypeTag[]`. I know that exact Map type is not accessible in runtime but want better solution than casting keys somehow (is this safe btw?) and doing `isinstanceof` for values.

Comment: Your code doesn't work. Inside `flatMap` you already have an `Any` not an `Option[Any]`. But otherwise it's a valid question. I think the answer is you can't do this.

Comment: @DanielDarabos `m.get` returns `Option[String]` so code is valid

Comment: @Suma I don't think this is a duplicate. You cannot solve the problem with `TypeTag`s

Comment: `m.get` returns `Option[Any]`. But that's not the point. `flatMap` let's you operate on the _inside_ of the `Option[Any]`. So you need `case m: Map[String, String]` and no `case None`. Just try it and you see.

Comment: @DanielDarabos ah, thanks.

Comment: @DanielDarabos That's still doesn't seem to solve the problem. `map.get("hello") map {case m: Map[String, String] => m.get("world")}` still doesn't check the value over being map with `String` key. Or what's your option?

Comment: I know it doesn't solve the problem. I believe there is no solution. (Unless you accompany every object in this structure with a `TypeTag` or you "promise" that all maps inside the structure have `String` keys.)

Comment: @DanielDarabos There is a solution, but it's overly ugly and unpractical. You could match `Map[_,_]`, iterate over keys and check their type. I do not have any other ideas unfortunately

Comment: I think I found a real duplicate, but I can no longer vote, as I gave up my vote earlier: [In Scala, how to test the type of an 'Any' object against a type with type parameter?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23155288/in-scala-how-to-test-the-type-of-an-any-object-against-a-type-with-type-param?rq=1) - even the code of the problem is very similar (JSON parsing as well).

Answer (score 2):

For this case

```
val value = map.get("hello").flatMap {
  case m: Map[String @unchecked, _] => m.get("value")
  case _ => None
}
```

is safe: if `m`'s key type isn't `String`, `get` will just return `None`! Another thing you could do is to work with an actual JSON AST, since you don't *really* have a `Map[String, Any]`:

```
sealed trait JValue
...
case class JMap(underlying: Map[String, JValue]) {
  def get(key: String) = underlying.get(key)
}
```

Now you can easily define what you want without casts or even potential unsafety:

```
val map: JMap = ...
val value = map.get("hello").flatMap {
  case m: JMap => m.get("value")
  case _ => None
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just for theory reason. It's possible to do this:

```
 val value = map.get("hello").map {
    case m: Map[_, _] => m collectFirst {case ("world", v) => v}
    case _ => None
  }
```

But it's overly complicated, and unpractical. Even worse, it searches the inner `Map` in O(n), when maps are supposed to be searched in O(1).

I don't think you can do it any other way, and I would not recommend even this one. There could be though solutions using the same idea, but simpler - unfortunately I could not think of any

Answer (score 0):

There is a elegant way to solve this using shapeless.

1) Declare a TypeCase

```
import shapeless._
val mapType: TypeCase[Map[String, String]] = TypeCase[Map[String, String]]
```

2) use it on the pattern matching to avoid the Type Erasure

```
val value = Map("hello" -> Map("world" -> "value")).get("hello").flatMap {
  case mapType(m) => m.get("world")
  case _ => None
} 
assert(value == Some("value"))
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
val v = for {
  nestedMap <- map("Hello")
  value <- nestedMap("world")
} yield value
```

Comment: It does not work as-is since the OP is having a badly typed variable from the start.